# can't loop through an object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I am not understanding how to loop through an object.
I have a state like this -

```js
const data = {
  name: "doe",
  age: "20",
  mail: "doe@mail.com",
};
const [user, setUser] = useState(data);
```

and in JSX I am looping the data like this -

```js
{user.map((userData) => (
    <li>{userData.name}--{userData.age}--{userData.mail}</li>
))}
```

and the error shows that :

```
TypeError: user.map is not a function
```

I want to know how to get a result like this :

```
doe--20--doe@mail.com
```

Comment: `map` is an Array function but you've set user to be an Object. As such you can simply access `user`.  `<li>{user.name}--{user.age}--{user.mail}</li>`

Comment: If any of the answers below helped, you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 1):

As `user` is an object you don't need mapping for this. you can directly access object property like this

```
    <li>{user.name}--{user.age}--{user.mail}</li>
```

Comment: @sazzad This answer doesn't give the result as expected by the OP. You should either modify the answer to give correct output or delete it altogether

Comment: sorry @Abhishek. i was a bit hasty to write the answer. now it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function on an array and not on an object. If you are willing to loop over the keys of an object, you can do it as follows -

```
Object.keys(user).map((objectKey) => yourFunction);
```

But, you don't even need to loop over object keys. If your object is small as it is, you can simply do it as -

```
<li>
    {user.name}--{user.age}--{user.mail}
</li>
```

---

### Final Code -

```
function someComponent() {
    const data = {
        name: 'doe',
        age: '20',
        mail: 'doe@mail.com',
    };

    const [user, setUser] = useState(data);

    return (
        <li>
            {user.name}--{user.age}--{user.mail}
        </li>
    );
}
```

---

### Alternate Approach -

If you want to make use of looping over keys of your object, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to achieve it(this will be preferable if your data has many keys). This can be done in the following way-

```js
const data = {
  name: "doe",
  age: "20",
  mail: "doe@mail.com",
};

let mystring = ''

Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
  mystring += `${data[key]}--`; // for each key, it will add append the key value and -- to mystring
})
mystring = mystring.slice(0, -2); // to remove the extra -- added at last
console.log(mystring);
```

Comment: If we're headed into Array territory... `const valueString = Object.keys(data).map((key) => data[key]).join("--");
console.log(valString);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use map function on object.

use Object.keys or convert the object to array of object like this:

```
const data = [{
  name: "doe",
  age: "20",
  mail: "doe@mail.com",
}];
const [user, setUser] = useState(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `user` the value of `data` meaning that it is now an object and you can directly access it key/value pairs.

```
const data = {
    name: 'doe',
    age: '20',
    mail: 'doe@mail.com',
};

function MyComponent() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(data);
  
  return (
    <li>{user.name}--{user.age}--{user.mail}</li>
  );
}
```